# Remove minimizd button in tkinter "root" window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to apply `transient` to `Tk()` instance. Example:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')

def create_new_window():
    win=tk.Toplevel()
    win.transient(root)
    win.geometry('200x200')
    tk.Label(win,text=' Hello World ').pack()

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Click the button')
label1.pack()

b1=tk.Button(root,text='New Window',command=create_new_window)
b1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

This code will remove the `▭` and `-` buttons. But, it will only do it for `tk.Toplevel()`:
The window on the left in the `root` window and the one on the right is `tk.Toplevel()`

[image]

But is there any way to remove the `▭` and `-` buttons on the root window? 
When I do:

```
....
label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Click the button')
label1.pack()

root.transient(root)

b1=tk.Button(root,text='New Window',command=create_new_window)
b1.pack()
...
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/91996/Documents/Visual studio code/cd.py", line 15, in <module>
    root.transient(root)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python3.8.6\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2233, in wm_transient
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'transient', self._w, master)
_tkinter.TclError: can't make "." its own master
```

I know I could simply do `root.resizable(0, 0)` or `root.withdraw()` after-wards. But I am exploring `tkinter` and I would like to to see implementation of `root.transient()`

If soomething obvious is missing, please be gentle.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The `Tk` object is a parent while the `Toplevel` is a child. Trying to make a parent `transient` should produce an error like this.  `_tkinter.TclError: can't make "." its own master`

Comment: I think only ```Toplevel``` windows can be ```transient```. You cannot use it for ```Tk()``` windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is code:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')

def create_new_window():
    win=tk.Toplevel()
    win.attributes('-toolwindow',True)
    win.geometry('200x200')
    tk.Label(win,text=' Hello World ').pack()

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Click the button')
label1.pack()

b1=tk.Button(root,text='New Window',command=create_new_window)
b1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey ther block! Your code helped me. I just needed to position ```root.attributes('-toolwindow',True)``` outside the function for ```root```. And it worked! Only the design is a little weird but its okay

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly standard implementation of a parent and transient child widget.

Child widgets **always** sit in front of the parent. If a parent is iconified (`parent.withdraw`) then so is the child but a child can be withdrawn or deiconified without affecting the parent by using `child.withdraw` and `child.deiconify`.

You may create many child widgets for each parent.

```py
import tkinter as tk

# Create parent
parent = tk.Tk()
parent.title("Parent")
parent.geometry("400x400")

# give tkinter time to create and position parent
parent.update()

# get parent position and size
x, y = parent.winfo_x(), parent.winfo_y()
w, h = parent.winfo_width() + 5, parent.winfo_height()

# Create child
child = tk.Toplevel(parent)
child.title("Child")

# make child invisible 
child.withdraw()

# make child the child of parent
child.transient(parent)

# set size and position of child
child.geometry(f"200x300+{x+w}+{y}")

# give tkinter time to create and position child
child.update()

# make child visible
child.deiconify()

parent.mainloop()
```